# Netbeans wont load html5 video

Tags: javascript, css, html, netbeans

I have a HTML5 web page, and I have a fullscreen video background.

When ever I try to run the webpage file by just clicking on the .html file through the folder in Windows, there is no problem.

But when i try to run it in Netbeans with the webserver as a HTML or PHP project, the video plays once, and then stops playing, while it has the atttribute of loop. And the looping does work when i open the .html file through windows.

On some video's its not even loading up the whole video, however the video controls are there. But the screen just stays black.

Is my code causing this problem? or the Netbeans application.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My site</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/plugins.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="fitScreen">

            <div class="loading"></div>

            <div class="mainContent">
                <video preload="auto">
                    <source src="sample.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video>

                <div id="logo"></div>

            </div>


        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
@import "reset.css";

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    font-family: Arial;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.fitScreen {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    height: 100%;

    background-color: black;
}

.mainContent video {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;

    height: auto;
    width: auto;

    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

And abit of javascript for a pre-loader ish thingy:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.loading').animate({'opacity': '50%'}, 1500, function() {
        $('.loading').fadeOut('fast');
        $(".fitScreen video").prop('muted', true); //mute
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.fitScreen video').fadeIn(2000);
            $('.fitScreen video').get(0).play();
        }, 250);
        $('#logo').delay(500).fadeIn(2000);
    });
});
```

I am currently using Netbeans 8.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are running the project on the NetBeans' embedded server? If so, try to run it in Chrome (from NetBeans, as usual), open Chrome Developer Tools, reload the page using F5 and switch to Network tab in Chrome Developer Tools and check the Type column for the row with the video record. There should be something like video/mp4 or video/[something]. It is possible that the embedded server doesn't support this mime type. If that's the case, check this link http://forums.netbeans.org/topic58110.html there is some workaround to enable it.

Comment: It works when i download the jquery-background-video from George Paterson on Github. But then when i try to change the video, to a video i have downloaded myself, In my chrome developers tools the video is'nt loading. But both of the videos are mp4 format. What now?

Comment: If one video is working fine and the other one not, I doubt it has anything to do with NetBeans. The fact that the video is not in Chrome Dev Tools is weird and I'm not sure how this can happen. Try to remove all the animations & jQuery stuff and make it simple plain HTML code to see if it helps.

Comment: You'r right, one video works and the other  not.But i have no idea how this comes. Whenever i open the .html just in Windows, there isnt any problem. I got one video wich is loading (the standard HTML5 launch oceans video). But that one is not looping, while i set the attribute to it. @ladar